# Is structure factor depends on how to choose unit cell?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

Consider FCC lattice, let lattice vectors are
$$
\vec{a}_1=a\hat{x}, \quad \vec{a}_2=a\hat{y}, \quad \vec{a}_3=a\hat{z}
$$
then basis are $(000),(\dfrac{1}{2}00),(0\dfrac{1}{2}0),(00\dfrac{1}{2})$, hence structure factor is
$$
S(v_1,v_2,v_3)=\sum_{j}f\exp(-2\pi i(v_1x_j+v_2y_j+v_1z_j))=f(1+\exp(-\pi i(v_1+v_2))+\exp(-\pi i(v_1+v_3))+\exp(-\pi i(v_2+v_3)))
$$
However, if considering a primitive cell of same lattice, then lattice vectors are
$$
\vec{a}_1=\frac{a}{2}(\hat{x}+\hat{y}), \quad \vec{a}_2=\frac{a}{2}(\hat{x}+\hat{z}), \quad \vec{a}_3=\frac{a}{2}(\hat{y}+\hat{z})
$$
Then there is only 1 basis, which $(000)$, since all other atoms are in another primitive cell. hence structure factor is simply $f$. What's the problem in this argument? Isn't structure factor own property of some crystal structure?